# Hyper-V Sending a Virtual Machine

Tags: hyper-v

I am new at using Hyper-V and have set up a Virtual Machine that I now need to send on to a 3rd Party.

Do I need to send the xml file that appears in the "Virtual Machines" directory as well as the vhdx file (hdd) or should someone just be able to work with the vhdx file?

I am unsure how the VM's work but sending copies is going to be a regular occurrence so I want to make sure I'm doing it in the easiest way possible.

Comment: Export the VM to a folder. Zip the folder. Send the folder. Instruct the recipient to import the VM from the folder.

Comment: @joeqwerty  Will the folder it exports just be the same as currently stored on the disk (the xml and vhdx) or does it export something differently (and more importantly will it be smaller)?

Answer (score 0):

the xml contains the configuration associated with the VM
Like Memory allocation,Network Adapters ...
if you like to export those configurations export this files with the Vhd(x)

Comment: The issue I am now having is our virtual image is around 200GB and to export it will take another 200 or so GB and then Zipping it even more and I just don't have enough disk space to do this until we upgrade. Is there a way of sending it on without needing all this disk space?

Comment: you can try compact the vhd to minimize the size

Actions->Edit Disk->locate Disk ->Compact